# how to make a recursive loop in python

Tags: python, recursion, request, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a web scraper that can cycle though pages using BeautifulSoup

To do this I am trying to write a function that makes a call to the page I'm looking for, finds the Href of the next button prints the result, then assigns it to the request and repeats the function recursively printing each new value of the next button.

This is what I have and I can't really figure out what it is not working. I get no error so I think my structure may be off.

Thank you in advance.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "http://www.calaiswine.co.uk/products/type/all-wines/1.aspx"
root_url = "http://www.calaiswine.co.uk"
first_index_url =  '/products/type/all-wines/1.aspx'

htmlFile = urllib.request.urlopen(url);

htmlText = htmlFile.read();

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText);

def cycle_to_next_page(foo):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen( root_url + foo)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
    items = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.findAll('a', title='Next')]
    print (cycle_to_next_page(items[0]))

cycle_to_next_page(first_index_url)
```

Comment: how does your recursive loop terminate?

Comment: what language are you trying to write in? there shouldn't be any **;** in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `print` just as @Jivan explained to actually call the function recursively, and you don't need to repeat the first `urllib.urlopen' call neither, you can open the initial page with the same function too. Something like this:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root_url = "http://www.calaiswine.co.uk"
first_index_url =  '/products/type/all-wines/1.aspx'


def cycle_to_next_page(link):
    response = urllib.urlopen(root_url+link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
    # my bs4 use find_all instead
    items = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a', title="Next")]
    print items[0]
    if items[0]:
        # here is the recursive function call, do a proper return, not print
        return cycle_to_next_page(items[0])
    print "crawling completed"
    return

# you can open your initial page with this function too
cycle_to_next_page(first_index_url)

#results:
/products/type/all-wines/2.aspx
/products/type/all-wines/3.aspx
/products/type/all-wines/4.aspx
...
```

Also, not sure if you just want `items[0]` or all items, anyway you may change the logic and call the function accordingly.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Your recursive function returns nothing**, it just prints.

In Python, a function that doesn't return is considered returning `None`. So, Python understands your `cycle_to_next_page(first_index_url)` instruction as if you did:

```
print(print(None))
```

I would personally not use recursion for this example. Just a basic `for` loop iterating through `items`.